# Custom AdapterView respond to its adapter's notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I am creating a custom adapter view. What I'm missing as a final step is to make it respond to its adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

When the data change e.g.:

```
myArrayOfData.remove(0); // remove first object
myAwesomeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I have to create a layout with the new, updated, data.

My question is should I add a listener (if so which listener and binded on which object)? Or should I override a method in my AdapterView (if so which)? I find the docs quite blurry here.

After the AdapterView has been notified for the changes as well, I will redraw the layout e.g. `requestLayout();`

Comment: see https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/BaseAdapter.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the `setAdapter` method in your custom AdapterView and register/unregister a `DataSetObserver`, something like:

```
private DataSetObserver mDataObserver = new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            requestLayout();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        if(mAdapter != null) {
            mAdapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
        }
        mAdapter = adapter;
        mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(mDataObserver);
    }
```

Comment: It works, may I ask why the unregister/register part?

Comment: The `registerDataSetObserver(observer)` adds the `observer` into a list baked by the adapter, and when the `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called, the `onChanged()` is invoked on every item in it. Calling `unregisterDataSetObserver(observer)` is not actually mandatory, but it's a good practice (you never know what happens with the old adapter, it might get reused, so if you skip the unregister part, the custom view will still react to it) and avoids possible memory leaking.